# Custom UITableViewCell imageView not updating after setImage

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, uiimageview, uiimage

I've got a custom UITableViewCell class whose model object performs an asynchronous download of an image which is to be displayed in the cell.  I know I've got the outlets connected properly in IB for WidgetTVC, I know that image data is being properly returned from my server, and I've alloc/init'd the widget.logo UIImage too.  Why is the image always blank then in my tableViewCell?  Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Widget *theWidget = [widgetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WidgetCell";
    WidgetTVC *cell = (WidgetTVC*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WidgetTVC" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.widgetTVC;
        self.widgetTVC = nil;
    }

    [cell configureWithWidget:theWidget];

    return cell;
}
```

In my WidgetTVC class, I have the following method:

```
- (void)configureWithWidget:(Widget*)aWidget {
    self.widget = aWidget;
    self.nameLbl.text = aWidget.name;
    [self.logoIvw setImage:aWidget.logo]; // logoIvw is the image view for the logo
}
```

Finally- I've got the callback method that sets the logo UIImage property on the Widget model object asynchronously (simplified):

```
 (void)didReceiveImage:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    // I pass a ref to the Widget's logo UIImage in the userInfo dict
    UIImage *anImage = (UIImage*)[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"image"];      
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
    anImage = newImage;
 }
```

Comment: Should I be passing a pointer to a pointer in userInfo instead so the async class can fill in the UIImage value?

Comment: Think I might need to see more code to answer this one. Your comment above the final code snippet says "callback method that sets the logo UIImage property on the Widget model object" - yet I can't see anything setting a logo property on anything in that method. I'm not familiar with ASIHTTPRequest, so I may be wrong but that whole method seems to be entirely passive, i.e. it does nothing. But you have written "(simplified)" above it, so maybe we do need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK- there were a couple things wrong here.  Thanks to bosmacs and Ed Marty as both of your comments were used to get to the solution.

First, I added a method to the Widget object to get the logo asynchronously:

```
- (void)asyncImageLoad {
    ...
    // logo is a UIImage
    [AsyncImageFetch fetchImage:&logo fromURL:url];
}
```

And my own AsyncImageFetch class looks like this:

```
+ (void)fetchImage:(UIImage**)anImagePtr fromURL:(NSURL*)aUrl {     
    ASIHTTPRequest *imageRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:aUrl];    
    imageRequest.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:anImagePtr] forKey:@"imagePtr"];
    imageRequest.delegate = self;
    [imageRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveImage:)];
    [imageRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(didNotReceiveImage:)];
    [imageRequest startAsynchronous];
}

+ (void)didReceiveImage:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    UIImage **anImagePtr = [(NSValue*)[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"imagePtr"] pointerValue];    
    UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]] retain];
    *anImagePtr = newImage;
}
```

Finally, per Ed, I added this to the configureWithWidget method that helps set up my WidgetTVC:

```
[aCoupon addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"logo" options:0 context:nil];
```

And when a change is observed, I update the imageView and call [self setNeedsDisplay].  Works like a charm.  Any way I can give you both points?

Answer (score 0):

In `didReceiveImage:`, you're only modifying the local pointer `anImage`. You need to set the `image` property of your `UIImageView` in order to update what gets displayed. Instead of stashing a reference to your widget's `UIImage`, pass a reference to the `UIImageView`, and in `didReceiveImage:` do something like

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"imageView"]; 
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
imageView.image = newImage;
```

Comment: But it still doesn't show an image even when I give the app plenty of time to ensure that the logo property was set *before* "configureWithWidget" is called as the cell is created (which calls setImage on the cell's image view).

Comment: What if I store a (UIImage**) in userInfo?  Would that work?  How do I need to modify the code to handle this (I'm a little fuzzy on all the pointer logic)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to access the image directly; wouldn't it be simpler keep a pointer to the image view and set it directly? Have you tried setting the image of your image view directly (with a local image) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to make sure it's working?

Comment: I store the logo image as part of the widget model object, and those exist whether or not there is a view to display them.  So when I need to display them in some context, I pull the logo image into an imageView...  Wouldn't it be odd to have a UIImageView as a property of a model object?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something... I'm not suggesting you add a `UIImageView` to your model object; I'm suggesting you pass it in `userInfo` in your request, which I assumed was context data for your callback. The point is I think you want to find a way to access the imageView and set the image directly rather than attempt to set it via pointer-to-pointer tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solution would be to have your model object have the image as a property and the display object subscribe to the image property's changes through KVO and update itself whenever the image property changes.